# How can this SwingWorker code be made testable

Tags: java, unit-testing, swing, tdd, swingworker

Consider this code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setEnabled(false);
    new SwingWorker<File, Void>() {

        private String location = url.getText();

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground() throws Exception {
            File file = new File("out.txt");
            Writer writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                creator.write(location, writer);
            } finally {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            }
            return file;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            setEnabled(true);
            try {
                File file = get();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FileInputFrame.this,
                    "File has been retrieved and saved to:\n"
                    + file.getAbsolutePath());
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread interupted, process aborting.", ex);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                Throwable cause = ex.getCause() == null ? ex : ex.getCause();
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An exception occurred that was "
                    + "not supposed to happen.", cause);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FileInputFrame.this, "Error: "
                    + cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + " "
                    + cause.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unable to open file for viewing.", ex);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

`url` is a JTextField and 'creator' is an injected interface for writing the file (so that part is under test). The location where the file is written is hard coded on purpose because this is intended as an example. And java.util.logging is used simply to avoid an external dependency.

How would you chunk this up to make it unit-testable (including abandoning SwingWorker if needed, but then replacing its functionality, at least as used here).

The way I look at it, the doInBackground is basically alright. The fundamental mechanics are creating a writer and closing it, which is almost too simple to test and the real work is under test. However, the done method is quote problematic, including its coupling with the actionPerformed method the parent class and coordinating the enabling and disabling of the button.

However, pulling that apart is not obvious. Injecting some kind of SwingWorkerFactory makes capturing the GUI fields a lot harder to maintain (it is hard to see how it would be a design improvement). The JOpitonPane and the Desktop have all the "goodness" of Singletons, and exception handling makes it impossible to wrap the get easily.

So what would be a good solution to bring this code under test?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Not a full answer: But if you like quality code, don't go near `SwingWorker`. In general factor things out. Where you have an API that uses statics/singletons introduce an interface with an implementation using the "real" static API and another for mocking (possibly another for auditing).

Comment: @Tom, if you have time to write up the outline of an alternative design to SwingWorker (or if you know of an alternative better implementation) it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO, that's complicated for an anonymous class. My approach would be to refactor the anonymous class to something like this:

```
public class FileWriterWorker extends SwingWorker<File, Void> {
    private final String location;
    private final Response target;
    private final Object creator;

    public FileWriterWorker(Object creator, String location, Response target) {
        this.creator = creator;
        this.location = location;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("out.txt");
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            creator.write(location, writer);
        }
        finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            File file = get();
            target.success(file);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            target.failure(new BackgroundException(ex));
        }
        catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            target.failure(new BackgroundException(ex));
        }
    }

    public interface Response {
        void success(File f);
        void failure(BackgroundException ex);
    }

    public class BackgroundException extends Exception {
        public BackgroundException(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause);
        }
    }
}
```

That allows the file writing functionality to be tested independent of a GUI

Then, the `actionPerformed` becomes something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setEnabled(false);
    Object creator;
    new FileWriterWorker(creator, url.getText(), new FileWriterWorker.Response() {
        @Override
        public void failure(FileWriterWorker.BackgroundException ex) {
            setEnabled(true);
            Throwable bgCause = ex.getCause();
            if (bgCause instanceof InterruptedException) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread interupted, process aborting.", bgCause);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            else if (cause instanceof ExecutionException) {
                Throwable cause = bgCause.getCause() == null ? bgCause : bgCause.getCause();
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An exception occurred that was "
                    + "not supposed to happen.", cause);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FileInputFrame.this, "Error: "
                    + cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + " "
                    + cause.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void success(File f) {
            setEnabled(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FileInputFrame.this,
                "File has been retrieved and saved to:\n"
                + file.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            }
            catch (IOException iOException) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unable to open file for viewing.", ex);
            }
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

Additionally, the instance of `FileWriterWorker.Response` can be assigned to a variable and tested independent of `FileWriterWorker`.

Comment: There are some nice ideas/idioms in that code snippet. Thanks, I'm going to chew it over a bit.

Comment: I just love this.

Answer (score 10):

The current implementation couples together threading concerns, UI and file writing - and as you've discovered that coupling makes it hard to test the individual components in isolation.

This is quite a long response, but it boils down to pulling out these three concerns from the current implementation into separate classes with a defined interface.

**Factor out Application Logic**

To start with, focus on the core application logic and move that into a separate class/interface. An interface allows easier mocking, and use of other swing-threading frameworks. The separation means you can test your application logic entirely independently from the other concerns.

```
interface FileWriter
{
    void writeFile(File outputFile, String location, Creator creator)
         throws IOException;
    // you could also create your own exception type to avoid the checked exception.

    // a request object allows all the params to be encapsulated in one object.
    // this makes chaining services easier. See later.
    void writeFile(FileWriteRequest writeRequest); 
}

class FileWriteRequest
{
    File outputFile;
    String location;
    Creator creator;
    // constructor, getters etc..
}


class DefualtFileWriter implements FileWriter
{
    // this is basically the code from doInBackground()
    public File writeFile(File outputFile, String location, Creator creator)
       throws IOException 
    {
            Writer writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(outputFile);
                creator.write(location, writer);
            } finally {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            }
            return file;
    }   
    public void writeFile(FileWriterRequest request) {
         writeFile(request.outputFile, request.location, request.creator);
    }
}
```

**Separate out UI**

With the application logic now separate, we then factor out the success and error handling. This means that the UI can be tested without actually doing the file writing. In particular, error handling can be tested without actually need to provoke those errors. Here, the errors are quite simple, but often some errors can be very difficult to provoke. By separating out the error handling, there is also chance for reuse, or replacing how the errors are handled. E.g. using a [JXErrorPane](http://swinglabs.org/hudson/job/SwingX%20Weekly%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXErrorPane.html) later.

```
interface FileWriterHandler {
     void done();
     void handleFileWritten(File file);
     void handleFileWriteError(Throwable t);
}  

class FileWriterJOptionPaneOpenDesktopHandler implements FileWriterHandler
{
   private JFrame owner;
   private JComponent enableMe;

   public void done() { enableMe.setEnabled(true); }

   public void handleFileWritten(File file) {
       try {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(owner,
                    "File has been retrieved and saved to:\n"
                    + file.getAbsolutePath());
         Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
           handleDesktopOpenError(ex);
       }
   }

   public void handleDesktopOpenError(IOException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unable to open file for viewing.", ex);        
   }

   public void handleFileWriteError(Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof InterruptedException) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Thread interupted, process aborting.", ex);  
                // no point interrupting the EDT thread
        }
       else if (t instanceof ExecutionException) {
           Throwable cause = ex.getCause() == null ? ex : ex.getCause();
           handleGeneralError(cause);
       }
       else
         handleGeneralError(t);
   }

   public void handleGeneralError(Throwable cause) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An exception occurred that was "
                    + "not supposed to happen.", cause);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(owner, "Error: "
                    + cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + " "
                    + cause.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

**Separate out Threading**

Finally, we can also separate out the threading concerns with a FileWriterService. Using a FileWriteRequest above makes coding this simpler.

```
interface FileWriterService
{
   // rather than have separate parms for file writing, it is
   void handleWriteRequest(FileWriteRequest request, FileWriter writer, FileWriterHandler handler);
}

class SwingWorkerFileWriterService 
   implements FileWriterService
{
   void handleWriteRequest(FileWriteRequest request, FileWriter writer, FileWriterHandler handler) {
       Worker worker = new Worker(request, fileWriter, fileWriterHandler);
       worker.execute();
   }

   static class Worker extends SwingWorker<File,Void> {
        // set in constructor
        private FileWriter fileWriter;
        private FileWriterHandler fileWriterHandler;
        private FileWriterRequest fileWriterRequest;

        protected File doInBackground() {
            return fileWriter.writeFile(fileWriterRequest);
        }
        protected void done() {
            fileWriterHandler.done();
            try
            {
                File f = get();
                fileWriterHandler.handleFileWritten(f);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                // you could also specifically unwrap the ExecutorException here, since that
                // is specific to the service implementation using SwingWorker/Executors.
                fileWriterHandler.handleFileError(ex);
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Each part of the system is separately testable - the application logic, the presentation (success and error handling) and the threading implementation is also a separate concern.

This may seem like a lot of interfaces, but the implementation is mostly cut-and-paste from your original code. The interfaces provide the separation that is needed to make these classes testable.

I'm not much of a fan of SwingWorker's so keeping them behind an interface helps keep the clutter they produce out of the code. It also allows you to use a different implementation for implementing the separate UI/background threads. For example, to use [Spin](http://spin.sourceforge.net/), you only need to provide a new implementation of FileWriterService.

Answer (score -1):

**Easy solution :** a simple timer is best ; you lanch your timer, you launch your actionPerformed, and at the timeout the bouton must be enabled and so on.

Here is an very littel exemple with a java.util.Timer :

```
package goodies;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class SWTest
{
  static class WithButton
  {
    JButton button = new JButton();

    class Worker extends javax.swing.SwingWorker<Void, Void>
    {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
      {
        synchronized (this)
        {
          wait(4000);
        }
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void done()
      {
        button.setEnabled(true);
      }
    }

    void startWorker()
    {
      Worker work = new Worker();
      work.execute();
    }
  }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      final WithButton with;
      TimerTask verif;

      with = new WithButton();
      with.button.setEnabled(false);
      Timer tim = new Timer();
      verif = new java.util.TimerTask()
      {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          if (!with.button.isEnabled())
            System.out.println("BAD");
          else
            System.out.println("GOOD");
          System.exit(0);
        }};
      tim.schedule(verif, 5000);
      with.startWorker();
    }
}
```

**Supposed Expert solution :** a Swing Worker is a RunnableFuture, inside it a FutureTask imbeded in a callable, so you can use your own executor to launch it (the RunableFuture). To do that, you need a SwingWorker with a name class, not an anonymous. With your own executor and a name class, you can test all you want, the supposed expert says.

Comment: I don't get why you would use a Timer to re-enable the button if the process might not have finished in that time, or keep the button disabled unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad english. It's not "must be enabled" but "is enable" I suppose. I edit my answer with some java exemple code. I hope it's more best.