# Java: How to unit test a SwingWorker

Tags: java, junit, mockito, swingworker

After googling this a while, I'm still not able to find an answer on this that I like.

I have a SwingWorker performing a "long" task, talking to a db and returning a result. I want to write a unit test for this, with a mock object for my db.

I have implemented my SwingWorker based on this great post here:

[How can this SwingWorker code be made testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081869/how-can-this-swingworker-code-be-made-testable)

But, it doesn't actually have the Unit Test logic there.  And I haven't seen any great articles on best practice, which leads me to believe that I'm missing something fundamental. Is it just as simple as a while loop checking for done?  Or is there something more sophisticated that I should be taking advantage of?  Or is best practice simply to build a synchronous access point to the logic under test?

-- Edit: I have added the Swingworker code to see how I'm implementing it.  So my question is: how do I write *effective* unit tests for this class?

```
public class MovieListLoaderWorker extends SwingWorker<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> {

//private Model model;
private MovieListDB db;
private Response target;
private boolean keepAlive = false;

public MovieListLoaderWorker(MovieListDB db, Response target) {
    this.db = db;
    this.target = target;
}

public MovieListLoaderWorker( boolean keepAlive, MovieListDB db, Response target) {
    this.db = db;
    this.target = target;
    this.keepAlive = keepAlive;
}

/**
 * @return List of movies (synchronous)
 */
public ArrayList<String> getMovieList() {
    ArrayList<String> movieNames = new ArrayList<String>(db.getMovieSet(true));     
    Collections.sort(movieNames);
    return movieNames;      
}

protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {
    target.started();

    // if we want to keep the Thread alive, we spin and publish movie lists
    while (keepAlive) {
        publish(getMovieList());
        Thread.sleep(Config.MOVIE_LIST_REFRESH_RATE_MILLIS);
    }

    // only run once, and simply return the Movie list.
    return getMovieList();
}

@Override
protected void process(List<ArrayList<String>> list) {
    ArrayList<String> s = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    target.statusUpdate(s);
    super.process(list);        
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> movieNames = get();
        if (movieNames == null) {
            target.failure(new BackgroundException(new Exception("Unable to load movie names.")));
        }
        else {
            target.success(movieNames);
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        target.failure(new BackgroundException(ex));
    }
    catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        target.failure(new BackgroundException(ex));
    }
}

public interface Response {     
    void started();
    void statusUpdate(ArrayList<String> list);
    void success(ArrayList<String> movieList);
    void failure(BackgroundException ex);
}

public class BackgroundException extends Exception {
    public BackgroundException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: avoid unit testing anything thread related. Separate out your core logic and test that directly using synchronhous unit tests. Test the threading as part of integration level testing.

Comment: It's a great idea.  I have moved my core logic to a public method that I can test synchronously.  However, my original question remains for Integration testing then.  What is the best way to test the threading aspect of the above class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here as an implementation of how to unit test a SwingWorker that I came up with that I'd appreciate any feedback on.  And if you're like me and had trouble finding a decent resource for this question, I hope it helps you.

First example is to take advantage of jodah.net's waiter functionality.  This will force the calling thread to wait until the SwingWorker returns.  You can do any required assertions on the results from the SwingWorker in the anonymous Response object, and makes exception testing straight forward.

```
//here's the Waiter import, among others that you'll need
import net.jodah.concurrentunit.Waiter;

@Test
public void testExecute_AsyncExample1() throws Throwable {

    final Waiter waiter = new Waiter();

    MovieListLoaderWorker mlw = new MovieListLoaderWorker(db, new Response() {

        @Override
        public void success(ArrayList<String> movieList) {
            waiter.assertNotNull(movieList);
            waiter.assertTrue(movieList instanceof ArrayList);
            waiter.assertEquals(3, movieList.size());
            waiter.resume();
        }

        @Override
        public void started() {                             
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(BackgroundException ex) {               
        }

        @Override
        public void statusUpdate(ArrayList<String> list) {              
        }
    });

    mlw.execute();

    waiter.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);      
}
```

The second example is fairly simple, and takes advantage of the fact that `SwingWorker.get()` blocks until it returns.  Exceptions raised by the SwingWorker will be passed to the caller when `get()` returns.

```
@Test
public void testExecute_AsyncExample2() throws Throwable {

    MovieListLoaderWorker mlw = new MovieListLoaderWorker(db, response);    
    mlw.execute();

    mlw.get();  //blocking so we can verify

    verify(response).started();
    verify(db).getMovieSet(true);
}
```

Two patterns that I worked out for myself.  Interested in other opinions.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get clear on the responsibilities here.

One part is that actual "Service" that has to talk to that DB and that you want to run via SwingWorker.

I would implement that *DBService* **completely** independent of a threading context. And that *DBService* class also has **no** relationship whatsoever to SwingWorker. It is a "standalone" class that provides a certain service, and that can be completely unit tested without worrying about SwingWorker or threads.

And then you create your own little SwingWorker that takes an instance of that *DBService* and uses that object to do its work.

Now you can give a mocked instance of *DBService* into your SwingWorker; and you can use unit tests to ensure that the "wiring" is correct.

In other words: don't push the full functionality into a SwingWorker. Instead, separate concerns here; because that also leads to a separation of "testing needs".

Comment: I added the class I want to write a unit test for.  MovieListDB is an interface to my DB service.

Comment: I only have my mobile phone keyboard here... And even with a real keyboard: keep in mind that we help with problems ; that doesn't mean that we do all the work for you. I can have a look into your code and make some specific suggestions ;but probably not before next week. If you are interested in such support drop me a reminder comment next Monday or so.